# Backbone end to fetch multiple collection

Tags: jquery, backbone.js

I have an in backbone where I fetch more collection, sometimes collection are empty sometimes contain data depends of the object retrieval from database. I want to know if there is a method to understand when all collection are fetched and then output my template, because if I render my template when a collection finish before another I can't see some elements like image or other things because isn't ready yet.

This is my view of my app:

```
var CombinationView = Backbone.View.extend({ 
        template: _.template($("#hotel-list-template").html()),

        showRooms: function(event){
            var id = $(event.currentTarget).attr('id').substr(5);
        },

        initialize: function(){ 
            this.hotels = new HotelCollection([],{ 
                url: '<?php echo base_url(); ?>json_upload/hotels_details_<?php echo($this->session->userdata("id")); ?>.json' 
            }); 

            this.amenities = new AmenityCollection([], { 
                url: '<?php echo base_url(); ?>json_upload/hotels_details_amenities_<?php echo($this->session->userdata("id")); ?>.json' 
            });

            this.image = new ImageCollection([], { 
                url: '<?php echo base_url(); ?>json_upload/hotels_details_images_<?php echo($this->session->userdata("id")); ?>.json' 
            });

            this.rooms = new RoomCollection([], { 
                url: '<?php echo base_url(); ?>json_upload/rooms_<?php echo($this->session->userdata("id")); ?>.json' 
            }); 

            this.hotels.on("sync", this.hotelsLoaded, this); 
            this.amenities.on("sync", this.amenitiesLoaded, this); 
            this.image.on("sync", this.imagesLoaded, this);
            this.rooms.on("sync", this.roomsLoaded, this);

            this.hotels.fetch(); 
        }, 
        render: function(){ 
            this.$el.html('Loading...'); 
            return this; 
        }, 
        hotelsLoaded: function(){ 
            this.image.fetch();
            this.amenities.fetch(); 
            var self = this;
            this.rooms.fetch({
                success: function(){
                    self.displayCombinations(); 
                }
            });
        }, 
        amenitiesLoaded: function(){ 
            console.log('amenities');
            this.hotels.each(function(hotel) { 
                hotel.addAmenity(this.amenities.getAmenitiesByHotelId(hotel.id)); 
            }, this); 
        },
        imagesLoaded: function(){ 
            console.log('images');
            this.hotels.each(function(hotel) { 
                hotel.addImage(this.image.getImagesByHotelId(hotel.id)); 
            }, this); 
        },
        roomsLoaded: function(){ 
            console.log('rooms');
            this.hotels.each(function(hotel) { 
                hotel.addRoom(this.rooms.getRoomsByHotelId(hotel.id)); 
            }, this); 
        },
        displayCombinations: function(){ 
            $(this.el).html(this.template({hotels: this.hotels.models}));
        } 
    });
```

Now I call the function displayCOmbination when rooms is fetched, but if rooms is esmpty I can't see for example the content of the collection of image because I have rendered before that the collection image is fetched.

How can I solve this?

Comment: Can't you have all those things nested in a single json? Also, why are you hooking all the events to your view? Since you are bootstrapping your hotel collection then have all those done within hotel collection…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the return from the fetches, as they use `jQuery.ajax` which returns `jQuery.Deferred().promise()` like this:

```
hotelsLoaded: function(){ 
    var self = this;
    var success = function(){
        self.displayCombinations(); 
    };
    var images = this.image.fetch();
    var amenities = this.amenities.fetch(); 
    var rooms = this.rooms.fetch();
    $.when(images, amenities, rooms).done(success);
}
```

Or more succinctly:

```
hotelsLoaded: function(){ 
    var self = this;
    $.when(this.image.fetch(), this.amenities.fetch(), this.rooms.fetch()).done(function(){
        self.displayCombinations(); 
    });
}
```

It will wait for all the fetches to be complete before running `success`